# Replacing master branch with forked branch in local environment

Tags: git, github, development-environment

My situation is this.

I've cloned a repo from Github, and setup a local environment to make sure it runs on my machine. Got it running, and then realized I forgot to fork off the main repo before cloning (doh).

Now I'm wondering how to replace the initial cloned repo with the repo I forked from github--all of this without losing the environment setup I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by changing the remote url in your local clone repository.

- Delete the current `origin`

  ```
  git remote remove origin
  ```
- Add the new origin which points to your fork

  ```
  git remote add origin <fork-url>
  ```
- Now fetch it

  ```
  git fetch origin
  ```

You may also wish to add the original repository as `upstream` to keep your fork updated.

```
git remote add upstream <original-repo-url>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new remote for your forked repository,

```
git remote add <new-remote-name> <forked-repo-url>
```

Fetch using,

```
git fetch <new-remote-name>
```

You can delete the existing remote, i.e. the main repository (`origin` by default),

```
git remote remove origin
```